# Always Returning Value zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
function getvalue(value) {
        document.getElementById('<%= hdnPack.ClientID %>').value = "0";
        var stdPack = 0;
        alert("a");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "test.aspx/GetStdSellingPack",
            data: "{'Col1':'" + value+ "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("b");
                if (data != null) {

                    $(data).each(function () {
                        var values = data.d;
                        stdPack = values;
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        alert("c");
        return stdPack;

    }
```

Am trying to execute this function Always returning zero , Actually what happening Alert(a) got Fired ,Then Alert (C) fired And Suddenly it goes to Alert(b). The result I would like to get In order, Alert(a) to execute first then Alert(b) followed by alert(c).Pl give me a solution .Thanks in Advance

Comment: look into returning a promise then resolve the promise in the ajax success. Your ajax call is async so your function will return before if acts upon your variable in the success callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax is asynchronous, so it can't guaranty the sequence of code executed. To return a value from function having ajax call check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)